# FluentMigrator not rolling back migration

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-migrator

I am using FluentMigrator (1.1.0) to manage database migrations in my project.  The migration project is a c# class library and I am using the fluent migrator tools to run the revisions.  My local environment is a windows mysql instance, but my dev environment is a linux mysql instance.

The other day while running the revisions against the dev environment a migration failed.  Upon inspecting the DB, I saw that the DB had not been rolled back to the state before the revision had executed.

Below is the revision that failed; why was the table not reverted to it's original state?  Columns A, B, and C are all still deleted.

```
public override void Up()
{
    Delete
        .Column("A").Column("B").Column("C")
        .FromTable("TABLENAME");

    Delete.FromTable("TABLENAME").IsNull("D");

    //FAILS HERE - !!! Cannot change column 'D': used in a foreign key constraint
    //'FK_TABLENAME_D_OTHERTABLE_COLUMN'
    Alter.Column("D").OnTable("TABLENAME").AsInt32().NotNullable();

    Create
        .PrimaryKey("PK_TABLENAME")
        .OnTable("TABLENAME")
        .Columns(new string[] { "D", "E", "F", "G" });
}
```

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Transaction-modes-for-the-migration-runner), they added support for migrations and I have verified that the default transaction behavior is 1 transaction per migration.  I also verified that it doesn't rollback this simple migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Delete
            .Column("A").Column("B").Column("C")
            .FromTable("Table");

        throw new Exception("e");
    }
```

I then tried this revision and it rolled back successfully.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("Table")
            .WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().PrimaryKey().Identity().NotNullable();

        throw new Exception("e");
    }
```

Thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Here is the revision for the creation of the table:

```
[Migration(49)]
public class _0049_CreateTableNameTable : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("TableName")
            .WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().PrimaryKey().Identity().NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("FK1").AsInt32().ForeignKey("OtherTable", "Id").NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("FK2").AsInt32().ForeignKey("OtherTable2", "Id").NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("FK3").AsInt32().ForeignKey("OtherTable3", "Id").NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("FK4").AsInt32().ForeignKey("OtherTable4", "Id").NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("CreatedDate").AsDateTime().NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("UpdatedDate").AsDateTime().NotNullable();
    }
}
```

Here is the revision for the deletion of the table:

```
    [Migration(53)]
    public class _0053_AlterTableNameTable : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Delete
                .Column("Id").Column("UpdatedDate").Column("CreatedDate")
                .FromTable("TableName");

            Delete.FromTable("TableName").IsNull("FK1");

           //FAILS HERE
           Alter.Column("FK1").OnTable("TableName").AsInt32().NotNullable();

            Create
                .PrimaryKey("PK_TableName")
                .OnTable("TableName")
                .Columns(new string[] { "FK1", "FK2", "FK3", "FK4" });
        }
}
```

Comment: Just did a quick test on Sql Server (I'll try out mysql later) and it worked for me. I created a table with four columns, A, B, C and D. And then executed your code (the Delete) and still had four columns. What did your table "Table" look like?

Comment: Ran the same test on mysql and it still works as it should. So I'm a bit stumped by this.

Comment: Before the delete revision begins, it has 7 columns.  After the delete revision runs and fails, it only has 4 columns.  It should roll back to having 7 columns.

Comment: Ah, of course. mysql doesn't (didn't?) have the same level of support for transactions. See here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluentmigrator-google-group/NU9W989htMo). I'll get back to you with a proper answer later.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug in FluentMigrator or just the way MySql works. I ran your migration 49 from your updated example but didn't have the tables for the foreign keys. MySql did an implicit commit after the create table part (as it does after all ddl statements by default) and then failed when trying to create the first foreign key. And afterwards the table was still there despite an attempt to roll it back. On Sql Server it does roll back the whole migration. I'm going to have to research this a bit more as I'm not sure proper rollbacks are even possible in MySql.

Comment: It's seem that the latest version (5.7) has the same issues regarding transaction and DDL statements.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation DDL statements cannot be rolled back. Sadly, I wasn't able to find a work around either.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Comment: Urls might be removed, little snippets of code or documentation from the link would help other users